# Create a magnet shape

Tags: modeling, mesh

I want to create a magnet out of a cube (prefer not to use any curves for this one).

I have extruded the cube to the following shape:

[image]

And added the subdivision surface modifier to get to this point:

[image]

Now I would like to make the left side rounder so it wouldn't look so boxy.
Something like this reference photo:
[image]

How could that be possible?

Comment: well, the best is probably not to begin with this shape  ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if you use the bevel operation to round the edges, it will probably fail because the faces will intersect.

If you want to create a magnet shape without beginning with a circle, you could create a cube, stretch it, duplicate, move these edges to tilt the end faces:

[image]

Then select the faces and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> (*Edge* panel) > *Bridge Edge Loops*:

[image]

Tweak the factors in the *Operator Box*:

[image]

Or use the Spin tool (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to rotate 5 by 5°), and extrude at the end, again you can tweak the parameters in the *Operator Box*:

[image]

Comment: No need to tilt the ends for _Bridge Edge Loop_ ?...  Blend Surface & Smoothness 1 ?

Comment: @Robin Betts it doesn't always work if the faces are not a bit tilted, or I miss something

Comment: How to avoid that? https://zupimages.net/up/23/17/b1l6.jpg (on the opposite faces it works fine)

Comment: Wow. Infuriating! I've tried flipping normals in weird ways, moving origins, orienting everywhere.. and can _not_ reproduce your flipped arch! ( I was originally thinking of bridging filled faces with correctly oriented normals, anyway) I guess that proves your point. If I _wanted_ it to go the 'wrong' way, how would I tell it to?

Comment: It doesn't happen if I select the opposite faces, I'm not sure the reason why: https://zupimages.net/up/23/17/nlu9.jpg

Answer (score 5):

This is a great example on the importance of the edge flow... I imagine moonboots will post a great modelling answer momentarily, so meanwhile here's how it can be done in geometry nodes:

[image]

You can then apply a modifier and add loop cuts with <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, or without applying a modifier, you can add a bevel modifier with 2 segments and Subdivision Surface modifier with 2 levels:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Or good old modifiers, using four vertices.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Start with a cube[image: cube]

then scale it (in edit mode)[image: scaled cube]

now we can bevel some edges like so [image: beveled cube]

and I know this might be cheating, but we can merge a cylinder and a cube with the boolean modifier like this.[image: boolean]

we can then use the boolean modifier again to cut out the center of the magnet.[image: this]

and we get this:[image: like this]

[image]

Comment: This produces ngons, which Subdivision Surface dislikes: https://i.imgur.com/cxPThfh.png however, if you're fine with just bevel modifier, it can still look alright: https://i.imgur.com/1Pri47r.png